# User makes lists from normal text in edits

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I saw a strange edit in the queue and checked if there is a pattern.
This user adds list markups to normal question text (and adds bold to some headers which is not bad but not something that warrants an edit to my mind)

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24825258
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24825265
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24823635

Basically my question is should this be notified somehow?
And if yes how/who shall I notify? (Asking on meta might just be solution I don't know)

Comment: Randomly making lists out of text that's not a list in any way is bad imo. Note that only one of these actually got reviewed by the queue (with 1 reject), the other two got accepted by the (low-rep) OP. If a user is making many bad edits, you can consider mod-flagging, but if you notice it in the queue you can just reject.

Comment: @ErikA Yes I think I rejected it, but OP approved and may even copy the style in the future.

Comment: You can ping them in the edited question using @username, but note that their name may not autocomplete. You can add a link back to this meta question in the comment.

Comment: I rejected or rolled back the last several harmful edits and reached out to the user. Because this was now handled by a moderator, I deleted your comment attempting to reach out. Let me take the brunt of this, if there is any. That's what moderators are for. Thanks for looking out!

Comment: @CodyGray Should I remove my suggestion to reach out to the user directly from my answer? I want to make sure I'm giving the right advice.

Comment: @Heretic Your advice is fine, and correct in general. It's just in this specific case, I took some...additional action since this was such an egregious pattern, so I don't want it to look like Kami Kaze is what caused that to happen. When a mod gets involved, it's best for it to *just* be the mod involved.

Answer (score 13):

The edits to make the paragraphs into lists did nothing to improve the posts readability, and, in my opinion, actively hurt their readability.

I would also say that adding bold formatting to the first question did not help either.

You can ping them in the edited question using @username, but note that their name may not autocomplete.

If there is a pattern of edits made, or they continue to make harmful edits after your communication, flag a question they've edited as **in need of moderator attention** and explain the pattern you're seeing.